# How does the Linux kernel decide if a block device gets the read-only flag set by default?

Tags: mount, kernel, usb-drive, block-device, readonly

I have a USB stick which (for about 2 months) constantly gets mounted read-only. After a bit of research and testing I found out, that the **block devices** of the device itself (`/dev/sdc`) and one of the partitions (`/dev/sdcX`) always has read-only flags (`cat /sys/block/sdc/ro` and `cat /sys/block/sdcX/ro` is 1).

I'm not talking about mount options! I have to manually set the flag to 0 with `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdcX` to be able to mount the partitions as read-write and to write at them (yes, writing works) every time I plug in the USB stick and after a reboot. The USB stick has no read-only hardware switch. I already formatted the partitions, re-created the partition table and even did `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc` to ensure that the old partition table gets destroyed completely, but nothing changed.

**NOTE:** Other devices however don't have this read-only flag set by default.

So how does the Linux kernel decide whether to set the read-only flag for a block device by default or not? And how can I change this behavior permanently and from early boot? (I actually boot my Raspberry Pi from this USB stick but the read-only behavior is the same on my laptop with different kernels...)?

Comment: Might be related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off

Comment: Are you looking for system calls (Kernel level) so that you can write a program, or a command that you can call from bash / other program Gnu/Linux OS level?